# Cosine distance matrix of matrix, GPU accelerate

Tags: python, parallel-processing, nlp, bert-language-model, cosine-similarity

I sincerely ask for your help. I have been stuck on this issue for more than 2 days. Simply speaking, when I want to calculate the distances of vectors, I just simply use:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_distances
distances = cosine_distances(vector_matrix)
```

where `vector_matrix` has a shape of [4,768]. I want to calculate the pairwise cosine distance of 4 vectors, each with 768 dimensions. Then I can get the distances matrix, a 4*4 symmetric matrix.

Last week I used sciBERT to embed some texts, then each text was encoded into a 512*768 matrix. Now my `embeded_text` is [4, 512, 768]. `cosine_distances` only accept vector not matrix. Is there a simple way to calculate cosine distance matrix between matrix(just like `cosine_distances`)? I can calculate matrix cosine distance one by one, but my real data is a [10663, 512, 768], GPU acceleration is a must.

Answer (score 0):

According to sklearn documentation of `cosine_distances`, their input parameters are
the shape of `(n_samples_X, n_features)` for the first features and `(n_samples_Y, n_features)` for the second features that you have, where `n_samples` in this case is your batch size (suppose it is your data, 4 is your `n_samples`).

then, what we need to consider about is your `(4, 512, 768)` shape that are text embedded using sciBERT. First, as I said, we already have 4 which is `n_samples`. the rest is `n_features` which requires a feature vector as an input for cosine distances calculations, but we have a matrix with (512, 768). This can be solved by reshaping the feature matrix into a feature vector instead via the `reshape` function.

```
# initialize a matrix with batch size 4    
matrix = np.random.rand(4, 512, 768)

# reshape into the shape (n_samples_X, n_features) required for cosine distances function, where n_features will equal to 512*768 and represented as a feature vector
reshaped_matrix = matrix.reshape(4, -1) # shape: (4, 393216)

print(cosine_distances(reshaped_matrix)) # output shape: (4, 4)
```

With that, we can still use the `cosine_distances` function the same as we use it with batched vector you have before to produce a cosine_distances value.

Comment: I total understands your idea. At first I also consider to flatten the matrix.  But this would bring a problem: when calculating the distance, the input data would be a vector with a shape of [393216], instead ofmatrices with a shape of [512,768]. In other words, the structural information would be lost when flattening from 2D to 1D.  I'm not good at BERT so I can't guruantee the result.

Comment: BERT embedding results are different from image. A 10*10 pixel image can be flattened into a vector with a shape of [100]. We both know [0] is adjacent to [10] for every vector. Structure information not lost when 2D to 1D. But in BERT embedding result, position[0] token is not always adjacent to [10] token in semantic space. That's what I'm worry about.